# “SQL Server” Error del Servidor “DELETE” e “INSERT” desde Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, importación, oledb

He creado un procedimiento que primero borra los registros de mi tabla y despues los importa desde excel.

```
DELETE tabla WHERE columna='dato'
INSERT INTO tabla
  SELEC * 
  FROM OPENDATASOURCE
    ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Data Source=\\compartido\carpeta\archivo_excel.xlsm;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0'
    )...[tbHoja$]
```

Al ejecutar, éste borra los registros. Pero al intentar conectarse a Excel para recuperar los datos me sale este mensaje de error:

---

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information
>   about the error.
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

---

He intentado crear un procedimiento donde solo se ejecute la importación y funciona, pero lo que necesito es que al llamar a un sólo procedimiento se borre e importe.

Ya que para solucionar esto he tenido que reiniciar el servicio del servidor y hasta ahora toma tiempo, además lo ideal es que sea automático y que las ejecuciones no sean tan manuales.

Comment: ¿El `SELEC` sin la `T` fue un error al copiarlo?

Answer (score 0):

1. Asegúrate que tienes los componentes o drivers de conexión.
2. Debes asignar al servicio de **SQL Server** un usuario de dominio con privilegios suficientes para usar el recurso de red al que estás intentando conectarte.
3. Ejecuta la siguiente:

Consulta:

```
use master
go
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure
go
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure
go
exec sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
go
exec sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
go
```

4. No olvides agregar el login del usuario que creaste para el servicio SQL Server con el rol de sysadmin